# android.os.DeadObjectException in firebase crashlogs

Tags: android, google-analytics

I recently added firebase analytics to my application. And have several instances of this fatal error in the firebase crash logs:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadObjectException
android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInstaller (ApplicationPackageManager.java:1641)
com.google.android.gms.common.zzo.zzy ()
com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.zza ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbco.zze ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbbz.onConnectionSuspended ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcw.onConnectionSuspended ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbbh.onConnectionSuspended ()
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.onConnectionSuspended ()
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzh.handleMessage ()
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:158)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5255)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:902)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:697)
arrow_drop_down

Caused by android.os.DeadObjectException:
android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Binder.java)
android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.java:496)
android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getPackageInstaller (IPackageManager.java:4196)
android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInstaller (ApplicationPackageManager.java:1638)
com.google.android.gms.common.zzo.zzy ()
com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.zza ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbco.zze ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbbz.onConnectionSuspended ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcw.onConnectionSuspended ()
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbbh.onConnectionSuspended ()
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.onConnectionSuspended ()
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzh.handleMessage ()
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:158)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5255)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:902)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

It has no references to anything in my own code. And I have not encountered it in testing at all. Has anyone else had a similar issue present itself, and know what these users might be doing to trigger this event, or have any insight into how this could be caused? The only major change I have made recently was to add firebase analytics, but because the issue has yet to show up in testing, I'm unsure if the issue is actually new or if I had just never had a tool to report it before.